# How do i store the multiple values of one xml node in spring boot?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have an XML response from the web service in the following format:

```
<main-node>
    <node>
        <id>101</id>
        <name>Test</name>
        <address>test</address>
        <address>test1</address>
    </node>
    <node>
       <id>102</id>
       <name>Jack</name>
       <address>New York</address>
       <address>London</address>
       <address>Canberra</address>
       <address>Cape Town</address>
    </node>
</main-node>
```

I created POJO classes and mapped them well and am able to store the values in a MySQL database. However, for the `address` field, only one of the addresses is being saved. How do I store multiple values inside the database?

This is the POJO I'm using for the XML structure mentioned earlier:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name="node")
public class Node{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I already tried using `String[]` for the `address` field, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Show the code for your POJO class. If it is only for 1 data value, it will not be able to catch both.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Use XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Comment: Where do i need to keep this piece of code? I am newbie here and sorry if my question is silly.

Comment: See this article https://stackify.com/java-xml-jackson/. You can get inputstream, and give it to the above mapper with the type of bean required as xmlmapper.readvalue(stream,Node.class)

Comment: @HimanshuThapa are you able to change the response format of the Xml Response ?  or you are forced to use it this way ?

Comment: @MohammadReza I don't think i can change the response format. I am actually working with cVent web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `address` field will be mapped to a column called `address` in MySQL, and database columns can only contain one value.

The solution is to create a one-to-many relationship, which means you need a separate `node_address` table next to your `node` table, that contains at least a `node_id` and `address` field.

[image: Schema of one-to-many relationship]

Now, for the JPA mapping, you can either go for a full `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` mapping, but in this case, using an `@ElementCollection` might be more interesting:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "node")
public class Node {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name="NODE_ADDRESS",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="NODE_ID")
    )
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private List<String> address;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

Since Hibernate (the default JPA provider) cannot map to arrays, you need to use a `List<String>` for the `address` field. If you don't like this, you'll have to create multiple classes, one for the XML mapping, and another one for the JPA mapping.

> **Note**: You're missing a mapping for your  element, so you'll have to create a MainNode class as well.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i had to make some twists in my code but this @Elementcollection worked.